# ASP.Net 5 app.UseStaticFiles() error out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1061  'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseStaticFiles' and no extension method 'UseStaticFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MyWorld.DNX Core 5.0    C:\Projects\MyWorld\src\MyWorld\Startup.cs  21
[image: ASP.NET5 Static File Issue]

Project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your project.json?

Comment: {
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}

Comment: @ShawnWildermuth i have updated with my project.json in my original question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your error message you can see that `UseStaticFiles` is available to `DNX 4.5.1` framework but not to `DNX Core 5.0`

You should add the dependency to `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` not only to `dnx451` but also to `dnxcore50` in your `project.json`. You can remove the depency in the `"frameworks"` key and put it inside the `"dependencies"` key to make it available for both frameworks

```
{
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
  },

  ...

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: For Asp.Net core MVC you need to install Nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles"